# Drupal 7 Views Module: how to fully customize output

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, view

I have defined a Content Type as "banner" which has only an image and Title, by the use of Views Module I'm trying to have the following output for the block's view

```
    <div style="background:url(IMAGE1_FULL_PATH.JPG)">TITLE1</div>
    <div style="background:url(IMAGE2_FULL_PATH.JPG)">TITLE2</div>
    <div style="background:url(IMAGE3_FULL_PATH.JPG)">TITLE3</div>
```

I have tried modifying the

```
views-view-fields.tpl.php
```

file and many others but couldn't have the desired output.
I believe that there is a themeing function that I should override to reformat the output..
Any Clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a much simpler solution is to use the option in Views to rewrite the output of the fields to your fancy. Click on the image field and check the box Rewrite output, then insert how you want your field to show:

```
<div style="background:url([image_field])">[title]</div>
```

You could then hide the original title field from the display. Make sure the title field comes before the image field in your field section, so the token [title] is available. Also make sure those are the correct tokens (you will see a list of available tokens at the bottom of the textbox when rewriting the field)

If, as you point out you don't have the URL, do you have "Link to node" option checked? Maybe the  is being generated becasue of that. If it's not the cause, then try one of these:

1. Set the formatter to Rendered file

   Set the View mode: Tokens

   Strip HTML tags (checked)

   You should see the token for the image as the full URL.
2. Create a new relationship
   Select your image field so that a relationship is created to the file entity
   Add a field to your view
   Select File: Path
3. Use a module called Views PHP which allows to have custom PHP code executed as the value of your field. There you will be able to access the field and read exactly what you want.

Anyway, check the Link to node option to be unselected as I mentioned at the top.

Comment: I have tried this, issue is that the replacement fields like [image_field] does not return the url.. I have tried using "Image URL Formatter" module, it returns url but wrapped in <a> tag.. anyway to output the **pure url only** ?